# How to get Android Version number in React-Native? (not API level number)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I want to display the Android Version in my app (like 8.0, 9.0...). For now I am using: `Platform.Version` But this returns the API version (24, 25...).

I would like an option that's more elegant than just creating a mapping, and that does not require republishing every time there is a new android release.
Is there a way to do that without an external library?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can :

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const OsVer = Platform.constants['Release'];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this library,

[react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info/v/0.9.1)

```
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()
```

apart from version, it has lots of methods which are much handy for getting device specific information.

**EDIT**: It is `getSystemVersion()`

Comment: `getVerison()` does not print the android version itself. It prints  the application version.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Platform.constants.Release**

Comment: it has Error : `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Platform.Constants.Release')`

Comment: @PurTahan which react native version you are using?

Comment: This constant is available only on Android, check docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform#constants

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options

1. Map values you are getting using `Platform.Version` with appropriate version number.
2. Use 3rd party library for example [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info/v/0.9.1), [getSystemVersion](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getsystemversion)

   ```
   DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this component

> react-native-device-info

[check](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getapilevel)

```
**Gets the API level.**

**Examples**


getAPILevel()

const apiLevel = DeviceInfo.getAPILevel();

// iOS: ?
// Android: 25
// Windows: ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Platform.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
const version = Platform.Version;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, but this is not a problem. If you console.log Platform.Version, it will return the target SDK version. With the help of targetSdkVersion, you can determine the device version (e.g., targetSdkVersion = 33 is for Android 13 and above). Alternatively, you can use the react-native-device-info package; it will provide you with the Device OS version directly.
you can checkout this also- https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform